# Find order of polynomial approximation and LeastSquares for given datapoints

Tags: fitting, interpolation, polynomials

I have a set of data, where I'd like to find the order of the polynomial that approximates the data, and also know what the Least squares is.

My data:

```mathematica
mydata={{30., 330.579}, {30.1, 326.98}, {30.2, 325.764}, {30.3, 
  311.321}, {30.4, 284.364}, {30.5, 316.126}, {30.6, 298.781}, {30.7, 
  294.901}, {30.8, 272.735}, {30.9, 268.916}, {31., 289.105}, {31.1, 
  269.206}, {31.2, 264.915}, {31.3, 266.102}, {31.4, 247.691}, {31.5, 
  269.225}, {31.6, 237.507}, {31.7, 243.386}, {31.8, 244.549}, {31.9, 
  227.996}, {32., 219.76}, {32.1, 225.659}, {32.2, 213.498}, {32.3, 
  204.988}, {32.4, 209.632}, {32.5, 205.647}, {32.6, 196.185}, {32.7, 
  212.885}, {32.8, 190.335}, {32.9, 181.173}, {33., 180.167}, {33.1, 
  161.973}, {33.2, 172.964}, {33.3, 166.16}, {33.4, 158.963}, {33.5, 
  156.729}, {33.6, 165.902}, {33.7, 149.723}, {33.8, 153.449}, {33.9, 
  138.211}, {34., 149.906}, {34.1, 135.848}, {34.2, 121.235}, {34.3, 
  128.755}, {34.4, 112.94}, {34.5, 110.743}, {34.6, 126.014}, {34.7, 
  108.869}, {34.8, 120.106}, {34.9, 115.747}, {35., 104.896}, {35.1, 
  97.7707}, {35.2, 101.916}, {35.3, 106.835}, {35.4, 98.4623}, {35.5, 
  91.2834}, {35.6, 79.0194}, {35.7, 84.4551}, {35.8, 80.7674}, {35.9, 
  92.3399}, {36., 84.6718}, {36.1, 83.8532}, {36.2, 77.6169}, {36.3, 
  73.0614}, {36.4, 76.7545}, {36.5, 77.824}, {36.6, 54.9666}, {36.7, 
  72.2144}, {36.8, 61.6352}, {36.9, 58.8691}, {37., 71.0184}, {37.1, 
  59.047}, {37.2, 62.543}, {37.3, 50.5073}, {37.4, 50.0954}, {37.5, 
  51.4783}, {37.6, 49.1749}, {37.7, 44.4528}, {37.8, 57.2066}, {37.9, 
  52.8937}, {38., 51.6243}, {38.1, 50.2519}, {38.2, 42.1921}, {38.3, 
  43.7001}, {38.4, 36.1474}, {38.5, 54.591}, {38.6, 59.4826}, {38.7, 
  38.8052}, {38.8, 38.2085}, {38.9, 48.2973}, {39., 31.7328}, {39.1, 
  34.4054}, {39.2, 58.3053}, {39.3, 51.7763}, {39.4, 51.1076}, {39.5, 
  41.9908}, {39.6, 37.1393}, {39.7, 48.3501}, {39.8, 59.6842}, {39.9, 
  28.208}, {40., 36.0402}, {40.1, 37.8059}, {40.2, 43.7093}, {40.3, 
  59.0266}, {40.4, 41.977}, {40.5, 41.1998}, {40.6, 34.4874}, {40.7, 
  36.4598}, {40.8, 45.7132}, {40.9, 42.5813}, {41., 55.5001}, {41.1, 
  45.6231}, {41.2, 42.7797}, {41.3, 34.9816}, {41.4, 59.9555}, {41.5, 
  59.1558}, {41.6, 58.1503}, {41.7, 50.0516}, {41.8, 58.8706}, {41.9, 
  53.63}, {42., 64.3079}, {42.1, 73.0313}, {42.2, 50.954}, {42.3, 
  70.9397}, {42.4, 57.6454}, {42.5, 68.1575}, {42.6, 55.2259}, {42.7, 
  80.7216}, {42.8, 74.3722}, {42.9, 70.1185}, {43., 85.038}, {43.1, 
  69.8574}, {43.2, 98.6267}, {43.3, 72.675}, {43.4, 90.1846}, {43.5, 
  85.838}, {43.6, 89.8398}, {43.7, 87.8715}, {43.8, 96.5692}, {43.9, 
  94.8867}, {44., 93.2906}, {44.1, 107.817}, {44.2, 110.883}, {44.3, 
  113.482}, {44.4, 110.891}, {44.5, 125.85}, {44.6, 117.684}, {44.7, 
  120.996}, {44.8, 109.709}, {44.9, 123.845}, {45., 121.603}, {45.1, 
  133.1}, {45.2, 124.626}, {45.3, 157.}, {45.4, 128.777}, {45.5, 
  152.501}, {45.6, 141.194}, {45.7, 164.115}, {45.8, 158.063}, {45.9, 
  162.978}, {46., 167.955}, {46.1, 173.832}, {46.2, 175.932}, {46.3, 
  179.225}, {46.4, 194.457}, {46.5, 187.11}, {46.6, 184.621}, {46.7, 
  196.59}, {46.8, 193.341}, {46.9, 229.232}, {47., 217.943}, {47.1, 
  212.923}, {47.2, 214.198}, {47.3, 213.599}, {47.4, 228.405}, {47.5, 
  219.229}, {47.6, 227.861}, {47.7, 236.055}, {47.8, 251.976}, {47.9, 
  244.459}, {48., 263.105}, {48.1, 258.907}, {48.2, 276.987}, {48.3, 
  260.376}, {48.4, 273.986}, {48.5, 285.245}, {48.6, 282.607}, {48.7, 
  280.599}, {48.8, 299.848}, {48.9, 312.727}, {49., 309.721}, {49.1, 
  302.612}, {49.2, 325.601}, {49.3, 318.055}, {49.4, 330.583}, {49.5, 
  336.413}, {49.6, 332.563}, {49.7, 357.118}, {49.8, 356.767}, {49.9, 
  351.579}, {50., 378.437}}
```

I started with plotting:

[image: data]:

My idea was then to create a Table containing exponentials (1, x, x^2, x^3...), and fit a function using the Fit method.

```mathematica
expo[n_] := Table[x^k, {k, 0, n}]
approx = Fit[mydata, expo[5], x] #example using order 5
```

Visualizing my result (here with order=5):

```mathematica
Show[dataplott, Plot[approx, {x, 30, 50}]]
```

[image: Order=3]

If my approach is correct, I don't know how to incorporate a range of evaluation numbers and see which is the best.

I also have been looking a bit at the `Interpolation` method:

```mathematica
interapprox = Interpolation[mydata]
interplot = Plot[interapprox[\[FormalX]], {\[FormalX], 30., 50.}, 
  PlotStyle -> Gray]
Show[dataplott, interplot]
```

This gives me an approximation output that looks pretty nice, but the `InterpolationOrder` seems to be default=3, so I'm not sure if this actually works (or perhaps how it works).

Output:

[image: outputplot]

Preferably I'm seeking a solution that also lets me get the Least Squares.

I might add that I'm rather new to linear algebra & mathematica, so apologies for any blunders.
Ciao.

Comment: You have to give some criterion what means "good". And a limit for what is good enough. And you have to specify if you want to smooth or interpolate.

Comment: @MelaGo 's advice about `LinearModelFit` is what you want.  And @DanielHuber 's comment is also critical as a "good" fit depends on the subject matter and your objectives.  You might consider asking this on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ because having a justifiable decision process is more of a statistical question rather than a *Mathematica* question.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, @MelaGo 's answer made me realize I had missinterpreted what I was suppose to do. I'm sorry if I wasted your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `LinearModelFit` instead of `Fit` makes it easier to extract various goodness-of-fit measures.

```
expo[n_] := Table[x^k, {k, 0, n}]
fittable = Table[LinearModelFit[mydata, expo[n], x], {n, 1, 6}];
```

For example, here are R-squared values for n=1 to 6:

```
Table[Show[dataplot, Plot[fittable[[n]][x], {x, 30, 50}], 
  PlotLabel -> "n=" <> ToString[n] <> ", R^2=" <> ToString[fittable[[n]]["RSquared"]]], 
  {n, Length[fittable]}]
```

[image]

You can see that the R-squared value gets very good at n=2, and only improves a small amount for larger n.

Comment: Thank you MelaGo, this very pedagogical illustration made me realize I've missinterpreted what I was supposed to do. Indeed it was to recognize that the shape of the data had the resemblance of an order=2 polynomial. Is it possible to continue with evaluating the LeastSquares with this approximation?

Comment: @OLGJ - Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by evaluating the LeastSquares. You can get the residuals, as shown in @JimB's answer, and calculate the sum of the residuals squared (`Total[resids^2]`); the model should be the result of minimizing this quantity. You can use `fittable[[2]]["ANOVATable"]` to see the variance.

Comment: calculating perhaps is a better wording that evaluating. :) Thanks for the pointers, I managed to calculate the LeastSquares with your help.

Answer (score 5):

I think your question is more of a statistical nature rather than a *Mathematica* question.  Asking this at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) might get you more targeted advice.

I'll repeat @MelaGo's and @DanielHuber's advice:  Use `LinearModelFit` and consider how good a result you need.  (It shouldn't be "I'll know it when I see it.")

One approach to deciding on which order of polynomial fit is relatively best is to use $AIC_c$.  $AIC_c$ can tell you which fit is best out of the models considered.  It is a "relative" goodness-of-fit criterion.  All of the models might be great or all of the models might be horrible but $AICc$ can tell you which is the best of those models in terms of statistical information content.  (I've stated that a bit loosely: again, you'd get better advice at CrossValidated.)

```
aicc = Table[{i, LinearModelFit[mydata, Table[x^j, {j, i}], x]["AICc"]}, {i, 2, 10}];
ListPlot[aicc]
```

[image: AICc vs order of polynomial]

A polynomial of order 3 appears to be the best of the models considered as that has the lowest $AIC_c$ value.

What about the meeting of the assumptions of the model for a polynomial of order 3?  One assumption is that the variability about the curve is constant for all values of the predictor variables.

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{mydata[[All, 1]], lm3["FitResiduals"]}]]
```

[image: Residuals vs predictor variables]

The variability looks relatively constant.

Are the predictions for the mean and an individual prediction good enough for your objectives?  One possible metric is the maximum size of the confidence interval half-widths.

```
Max[Differences[#] & /@ lm3["MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervals"] // Flatten]/2
(* 4.43511 *)
Max[Differences[#] & /@ lm3["SinglePredictionConfidenceIntervals"] // Flatten]/2
(* 16.6166 *)
```

So if +/-4.4 for the mean and +/- 16.6 for a single prediction is good enough, then you're done.  But you need to decide on that.

Answer (score 1):

There's always the magic of `FindFormula`:

```
FindFormula[mydata, x]

(*  4903.25 - 245.055 x + 3.08796 x^2  *)
```

But usually one starts from a theoretical basis that suggests the form of the model....